# Java Regex ignoring/commenting out part of regex

Tags: java, regex, string

**I have searched a lot about how to ignore part of RegEx expression. Here's why.**

RegEx example:

```
".*atan2\\(.*\\).*"
```

It will detect the function 'atan2' like so:

```
string.matches("return atan2(45, 23)")
```

But as I bring in another String:

```
string.matches("return atan2("+Integer.valueOf(XInString)+", 58)")
```

And if XInString looks like that: `45.7` regex will be affected of that dot, because regex will look like that then: `"return atan2(45.7, 58)"` and the point between 5 and 7 is a part of regex. Is there a way to ignore that part?
For example:

```
string.matches("return atan2([45.7], 58)")
```

(The string between [ and ] is what i don't want regex to read)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...the point between 5 and 7 is a part of regex. Is there a way to
>   ignore that part?

Yes, you can escape that dot using `Pattern.quote(XInString)` like this :

```
"return atan2(" + Pattern.quote(XInString) + ", 58)"
```